# How do I install Muvizu on Ubuntu 14,04 LTS?

Tags: wine

One of the most used software when I using the windows operating system was Muvizu. 
Now that I have migrated to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I am trying to explore the possibilities of installing and running  Muvizu on Ubuntu.

I have done alot of research on  the matter but it seems like no one has successfully installed and run it, even when using Wine.

Does anyone know how I can successfully install and run Muvizu on Ubuntu?

Looking forward to your reply.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think muvizu is only used for windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you browse it on Wine website?
I think the best choice would be dual boot, and still use Windows to run this app, untill there's a Linux version or another software with the same tools.